# how to write "insert" in vector?

Tags: c++

I write this,but it didn't work...

```
template<typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator vector<T>::insert(iterator pos,const T& val)
{
    int a=0,b=0;
    if(capacity()==0) a=capacity()+1;
    if(capacity()==size())
    {
        a=capacity()*2;
        T *start2=operator new[](a*sizeof(T)))
        for(int i=0;;i++)
        {
             new(start2+i) T(start+i);
             if(start2+i==pos)
             {
                 b=start2+i;
                 break;
             }
        }
        start2+pos=val;
        for(int j=b;j<=2*size();j++)
        {
             new(start2+j) T(start+j+1);
        }
    }
    else if(capacity()>size())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=capacity();i++)
        {
            if(start+i==pos)pos=
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this is obviously C++ and not C#... please define "didn't work" or this is likely to be closed.

Comment: `if(start+i==pos)pos=` is not a complete statement.

Comment: `T *start2=operator new[](a*sizeof(T)))` O.O Why like this?

Comment: Unless you can provide code which compiles and more detail about what "didn't work" I'm inclined to say just use `std::vector` if you are having trouble re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry not say very complexly.I new a*sizeof(T) is because when capacity()==size(),there were no space,I know I still not finish it...but I fell strange that I write wrong...

Comment: very thanks,by the way...how do I watch content in "std::vector"?

Answer (score 2):

Use [insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) or [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) functions provided for [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

There is already [an insert() function in std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/).